# How to update content in dynamic URLs in Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

Below have I created 3 URL's from the `fn` array. In real life, this would be approx 200 different filenames.

After I have created them, would I like to be able to update the content of the URL's to be either `1` or `0`.

With the below PoC, the content doesn't change.

**Question**

Does anyone know how I can change the content of the URL's on-the-fly?

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const fn = ['filename1', 'filename2', 'filename3'];

for (const e of fn) {
  app.get(`/${e}`, (req, res) => {
    res.send(e);
  });
};

app.get(`/filename1`, (req, res) => {
  res.send('test');
});

const port = 1900;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`http://localhost:${port}/`);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create one wildcard route listener and add your logic inside of it

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const fn = ['filename1', 'filename2', 'filename3'];

app.get("/*", (req, res) => {
  // Do your logic inside
  if(fn.includes(req.url.replace('/',''))) return res.send('ok');
  
  res.status(404).send('Not Found');
});


const port = 1900;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`http://localhost:${port}/`);
});
```

Comment: When I test it with `curl localhost:1900/filename1` then it doesn't return anything, but it doesn't exit either. It is as if it is waiting.

Comment: Made an edit: It was waiting because of `res.status(404)` with `.send` in it should be resolved.